# Infer generic type parameters in TypeScript over multiple levels

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I have the following common scenario in my TypeScript code:

```
interface TopLevelInterface<A extends BottomLevelInterface<B>, B>
```

and an implementation for `BottomLevelInterface` that looks like this:

```
class BottomLevelClass implements BottomLevelInterface<MyType>
```

My question is: When implementing `TopLevelInterface` I not only need to pass the type argument for `A` which would be `BottomLevelClass`, but also the second type argument for `B` which would be `MyType` in the above example.

Why do I need to specify `B` which could easily be inferred by looking at the type argument of `BottomLevelClass` ?

For example, when implementing `TopLevelInterface` I need to specify the following:

```
class TopLevelClass implements TopLevelInterface<ConcreteBottomLevel, MyType>
```

Instead of the shorter version that should be sufficient:

```
class TopLevelClass implements TopLevelInterface<ConcreteBottomLevel>
```

Why is this necessary? How can I infer the second type argument by looking at the first one? The only solution I came up with is using `infer` in TypeScript 2.8+ with a default assignment. This solution looks like this:

```
interface TopLevelInterface<A extends BottomLevelInterface<B>, 
    B = A extends BottomLevelInterface<infer _B> ? _B : any>
```

However, I'm not able to correctly apply this with a three-layer class hierarchy. In the following StackBlitz you can see that I cannot get the correct type constraint for the property `model` of `TopLevelClass`. It should be inferred to the type `SomeType` but instead is inferred to `never`. At `MiddleLevelClass` it does work correctly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pcxnzo?file=infer-generics.ts

Can anyone explain the issue or a better way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I don't know why you need these interfaces with these particular type parameter constraints and relationships, but assuming you do, I don't think you can do better than the `infer`.  You can solve the immediate problem with the three levels by replacing `M extends MiddleLevelInterface<B>` with `M extends MiddleLevelInterface<B, T>` in the definition of `TopLevelInterface`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the error. However, I still don't get the correct constraints when implementing `TopLevelInterface`. I've updated my StackBlitz to show the effect. The property `z` in `TopLevelClass` should have a constraint for `SomeType`, but is assignable to any type, while in `MiddleLevelClass` we get the correct constraints. Do you think this might be a limitation of TypeScript?

Comment: Can anyone find an issue or feature request for this on Typescripts github?  It seems like this should exist, and I'm surprised I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deliberate error in `MiddleLevelClass` is affecting the behavior of `TopLevelClass`, so for a valid test, we should base `TopLevelClass` on a correct `MiddleLevelClass` and use a separate `BadMiddleLevelClass` to demonstrate the error there.

Your first problem is that your conditional types have an "else" case of `any`, which will tend to hide errors.  `never` tends to be better and is commonly used, though a full solution would require [a unique `invalid` type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689).

With these changes, it seems the main problem is that when you write `TopLevelInterface<MiddleLevelClass>` and TypeScript tries to evaluate `B = M extends MiddleLevelInterface<infer _B> ? _B : never`, there are no inferences for `_B` because the `B` parameter is not actually used by `MiddleLevelInterface` or `MiddleLevelClass`.  See [this FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot---).  Adding a dummy optional property that uses `B` fixes the problem.  (I guess you used `B` for something in your real application, otherwise you wouldn't have declared `B`, but you removed the use in the simplified example?)

New code:

```
export class SomeType {
  x: string;
}

export interface BottomLevelInterface<T> {
  model : T;
}

export class BottomLevelClass implements BottomLevelInterface<SomeType> {
  model: SomeType;
}

export interface MiddleLevelInterface<B extends BottomLevelInterface<T>, 
    T = B extends BottomLevelInterface<infer _T> ? _T : never> {
  _dummy_B?: B;

  model: T;
} 

export class MiddleLevelClass implements MiddleLevelInterface<BottomLevelClass> {
  _dummy_B?: BottomLevelClass;
  model: SomeType;
}

export class BadMiddleLevelClass implements MiddleLevelInterface<BottomLevelClass> {
  // here we correctly see an error from TypeScript service, as 'string' cannot be applied to 'SomeType'
  model: string;
}

export interface TopLevelInterface <M extends MiddleLevelInterface<B, T>,
    B extends BottomLevelInterface<T> = M extends MiddleLevelInterface<infer _B> ? _B : never,
    T = B extends BottomLevelInterface<infer _T> ? _T : never> {

  model: T;
}

export class TopLevelClass implements TopLevelInterface<MiddleLevelClass> {
  // now there is an error here
  model: string;
}
```

Alternative solution to the original problem based on jcalz's suggestion (thanks!): Instead of using multiple type parameters, use helper type aliases to determine the `T` type from the `B` type and the `B` type from the `M` type every time you need them.  Here's the code:

```
export class SomeType {
  x: string;
}

export interface BottomLevelInterface<T> {
  model : T;
}

export class BottomLevelClass implements BottomLevelInterface<SomeType> {
  model: SomeType;
}

type TfromB<B extends BottomLevelInterface<any>> = B extends BottomLevelInterface<infer T> ? T : never;

export interface MiddleLevelInterface<B extends BottomLevelInterface<any>> {
  _dummy_B?: B;

  model: TfromB<B>;
} 

export class MiddleLevelClass implements MiddleLevelInterface<BottomLevelClass> {
  _dummy_B?: BottomLevelClass;
  model: SomeType;
}

export class BadMiddleLevelClass implements MiddleLevelInterface<BottomLevelClass> {
  // here we correctly see an error from TypeScript service, as 'string' cannot be applied to 'SomeType'
  model: string;
}

type BfromM<M extends MiddleLevelInterface<any>> = M extends MiddleLevelInterface<infer B> ? B : never;

export interface TopLevelInterface <M extends MiddleLevelInterface<any>> {

  model: TfromB<BfromM<M>>;
}

export class TopLevelClass implements TopLevelInterface<MiddleLevelClass> {
  // now there is an error here
  model: string;
}
```

I wouldn't be surprised though if the reliance on conditional types instead of explicit type parameters makes certain operations that go beyond this simple example more difficult.  You can try it and see.

Comment: Is there a reason we want to use multiple type parameters instead of a single one?  e.g., `type TfromB<B extends BottomLevelInterface<any>> = B extends BottomLevelInterface<infer T> ? T : never` and then `interface MiddleLevelInterface<B extends BottomLevelInterface<any>> { _dummy_B?: B; model: TfromB<B>; }` etc, down to `TfromB<BfromM<M>>`?

Comment: @jcalz It works for me, at least in the example so far; I wouldn't be surprised though if the heavier use of conditional types causes problems later.  Do you want to post another answer or shall I add the alternative solution to mine?

Comment: I'll bow out here; you can edit your answer if you feel like it.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you both for your efforts!

Comment: Thanks for the first example. I was looking for an example of inferring type and this question and answer is just the thing I need.

Comment: this solution is great and all, but if we don't know the expected levels in advance or if the levels in the middle are not each using a separate interface it still won't help with getting the actual generic type expected. I don't understand why TypeScript just doesn't go further inside of the inheritance tree to find the actual interface mentioned.